# How to get instance of Interface annotated as Service via Application Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I've written a library using spring for usage in both non spring and Spring Boot based apps.

I use a messaging gateway to expose the Integration flow as a plain old java interface for use by other classes

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface SwiftalkKafkaGateway {

    @Async
    void publish(Message<?> message);
}
```

I'm facing trouble getting an instance of this gateway class via Spring Context; one of the apps using this library runs in a JavaEE 8 CDI enviornment; for which I wrote a loader like so

```
@Singleton
@ApplicationScoped
public class SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader {

    private final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext springContext;

    SwiftalkAnnotatedSpringContextLoader(String propertiesFile) throws IOException {
        springContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardEnvironment();
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        Properties appProps = new Properties();
        appProps.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFile));
        propertySources.addFirst(new PropertySource<Properties>("spring-properties", appProps) {
            @Override
            public Object getProperty(String name) {
                return appProps.getProperty(name);
            }
        });
        springContext.setEnvironment(environment);
        springContext.scan("com.foo.cloud.swiftalk");
        springContext.refresh();
    }

    ApplicationContext getSwiftalkKafkaClientContext() {
        return this.springContext;
    }

}
```

however getting bean instance fails

```
    SwiftalkKafkaGateway kafkaGateway = loader.getSwiftalkKafkaClientContext().getBean(
            SwiftalkKafkaGateway.class);
    assertNotNull(kafkaGateway);
```

with the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.foo.cloud.swiftalk.SwiftalkKafkaGateway' available
```

which occurs due to

```
21:37:42.003 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/Users/anadimishra/.m2/repository/com/foo/cloud/swiftalk-kafka-client/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/swiftalk-kafka-client-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/com/foo/cloud/swiftalk/SwiftalkKafkaGateway.class]
```

How do I get an instance of this Service for usage in non spring environments?

**Update**

The integration flow where I use this

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow kafkaPublisherFlow(KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> kafkaProducerMessageHandler,
                                          RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice,
                                          ExecutorChannel kafkaPublishChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(SwiftalkKafkaGateway.class)
            .channel(kafkaPublishChannel)
            .handle(kafkaProducerMessageHandler, e -> e.advice(retryAdvice))
            .get();
}
```

The idea is to be able to reuse this kafka publisher with error handling and idempotent operations code in both spring boot and non spring boot apps.

Comment: Do you have `@EnableIntegration` on one of your `@Configuration` classes? Also, show the integration flow.

Comment: hey Gary, I'm using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` do I still need to put `@EnableIntegration` ?

Comment: ?? `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is for Spring Boot, which you are not using, if you want auto configuration, you should be using `SpringApplication` or `SpringApplicationBuilder` to create the application context, not creating an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Comment: `SpringApplicationBuilder` fixed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Sprint Boot's `@EnableAutoConfiguration, you should be using` SpringApplication`or`SpringApplicationBuilder`to create the application context, not creating an`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.